# convert Class object to bytes

Tags: java, classloader

If I have a [Class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) instance at runtime, can I get its byte[] representation?  The bytes I'm interested in would be in the [Class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html), such that they'd be valid input to  [ClassLoader.defineClass][3].

[3]: http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass(java.lang.String, byte[], int, int)

EDIT: I've accepted a getResourceAsStream answer, because it's very simple and will work most of the time.  ClassFileTransformer seems like a more robust solution because it doesn't require that classes be loaded from .class files; it would handle network-loaded classes for example.  There's a few hoops to jump through with that approach, but I'll keep in in mind.  Thanks all!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7980133/converting-a-given-class-lets-say-java-lang-object-to-a-byte-array-is-it-po

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can usually just load the class as a resource from the Classloader.

```
Class c = ...
String className = c.getName();
String classAsPath = className.replace('.', '/') + ".class";
InputStream stream = c.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(classAsPath);
```

I would probably recommend using something from Apache commons-io to read the InputStream into a `byte[]`, but `IOUtils.toByteArray()` should do the trick.  Writing that code is really easy to get wrong and/or make slow.

Comment: and how to compile the class back on the other side when I receive this message as `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: Creating classes from bytes is the job of a ClassLoader.

Comment: Hi, if the class is a proxy class and dynamic be generated at runtime, and stored in the memory, how can we save it to a file?

Comment: How to do the reverse? that is to convert byte[] to java.lang.Class?

Comment: If you want to recreate the class from the buffer, then look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75503621/16028444)

Answer (score 2):

In general you can't go back like that. However, for some class loaders you may be able to get the resource file be taking the fully qualified class name, replacing `.` with `/` and appending `.class` (so `mypackage.MyClass` becomes `mypackage/MyClass.class` (remember, may be case sensitive)).

Answer (score 2):

You can try java [instrumentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html)! In particular [ClassFileTransformer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html) maybe of interest to you!!

You simply override the transform method (from ClassFileTransformer), and your transform method will be called before each class is loaded. So then you cna do whatever class bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [ClassFileTransformer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100207011321/http://www.sixlegs.com/blog/java/definalizer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit of help,

use

```java
final Class<T> clazz = ...
final byte[] buffer = clazz.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(clazz.getName().replace('.', '/').concat(".class"));
```

to get the compiled byte code of the class.

---

And use

```java
class SimpleClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    public Clazz<?> loadFromBuffer(final byte[] buffer) {
        return defineClass(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    }

    public Object newObjectFromBuffer(final byte[] buffer) {
        return loadFromBuffer(buffer).newInstance();
    }

}
```

to instantiate an `Object` or to load the `Class` back from the buffer.