# Converting a given class (let's say, java.lang.Object) to a byte array. Is it possible?

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

Given that class loaders accept to take as input a byte array of a given class, returning a `Class<?>`, I wonder whether it is possible to do the reverse, that is, to pass a `Class<?>` and get its byte array?

Keep in mind that I'm not talking about serialization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ClassLoader.getResourceAsInputStream() however it is not guaranteed this will be the same bytes as that which was loaded. I don't believe the actual bytes loaded are stored anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

No standard way I know of. But you might implement your own delegating classloader, keeping track of classes loaded in terms of name and bytecode.

What would be your use case? - Transferring code to a remote application?

Answer (score 2):

A `ClassLoader` implementation must grok the representation of a class for the Java Language Specification version it supports. So it has to contain the logic to take a byte array and turn this into a `Class` object, or extend some ClassLoader that does. However, the abstract `ClassLoader` class that Java defines doesn't have any method that can return a byte[] from a Class. It is possible that some implementations have this (perhaps the bootstrap, system or other class loader), but that'd be implementation-specific at best and not something to rely on.

If you require this kind of functionality, one way to do it would be to create your own `ClassLoader` implementation and override the `defineClass` methods in such a way that the input byte arrays are mapped to `Class` objects so they can later be retrieved.

Since a compiler turns source code into class files (basically the byte[]) and a class loader turns class files into `Class` objects, there's nothing in the chain that's directly suitable to go from `Class` to a byte[]. But with the stuff out there that does byte code weaving, runtime byte code generation and the like, you might find something that can do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something to try with [BCEL](http://commons.apache.org/bcel/):

```
JavaClass clazz = Repository.lookupClass("foo.bar.YourClass");
byte[] bytes = clazz.getBytes();
```

I didn't know the answer prior to reading your question, but I knew I should check the following libraries, because they support the [Java class file format](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#80959):

- BCEL
- javassist
- asm

If the above doesn't work, look for something else in these libraries.